# ¿Cómo puedo enviarle valores al padre desde un popup usando javascript en vb.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

La página padre invoca al popup con lo siguiente:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_boton_cp" runat="server">
<input style="width:33px; height:24px; font-weight:bold" onclick="window.open('codigopostal.aspx?5313C=DIRCL', 'Cliente', 'width=530,height=440,scrollbars=yes')" value="CP" type="button" />
```

Y en la página hija, tengo que cuando presionen el botón de aceptar se ejecute el siguiente código:

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_cp.value='" & e.Item.Cells(1).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_col.value='" & e.Item.Cells(2).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_pobmun.value='" & e.Item.Cells(4).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_ciudad.value='" & e.Item.Cells(6).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_ciudad.value='" & e.Item.Cells(6).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.opener.document.forms[0].Text_estado.value='" & e.Item.Cells(5).Text & "'; ")
            Response.Write("window.close(); ")
            Response.Write("</script> ")
```

Este es el error que me arroja:
[image: Pero no veo que mi value sea nulo]

En la página padre todavía no tengo puesto que haga algo, pero veo que la página hija no se cierra y solo queda el texto del grid (que es de donde tomo los valores) en negrita.

Comment: depende de muchas cosas, como es que inicializas el popup, que hace la ventana principal cuando recibe, la pregunta en sí está incompleta.

Comment: He agregado más información.

Comment: En la primera linea tienes un diagonal quitalo pa' que quede asi: `Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript""> ")`

Comment: Cierto, igual veo que me falta un =, actualizo el código y les mostraré el error que me arroja.

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que hice lo siguiente:

Usé variables de sesión en la página hija y solo les asigné el valor y cerré la ventana con un javascript.

```
Session("Text_cp") = e.Item.Cells(1).Text
Session("Text_col") = e.Item.Cells(2).Text
Session("Text_pobmun") = e.Item.Cells(4).Text
Session("Text_ciudad") = e.Item.Cells(6).Text
Session("Text_estado") = e.Item.Cells(5).Text
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>")
Response.Write(" var loc = window.opener.location; ")
Response.Write(" window.opener.location = loc; ")
Response.Write(" window.close(); ")
Response.Write("</script> ")
```

Y listo, no es precisamente lo que quería hacer pero me funcionó. Les agradezco por su tiempo.